# Write a xml schema that can be converted to Java with a Set attribute

Tags: java, xml, collections, jaxb

Suppose we have the following xml schema type definiton:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="StateType">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
   <xsd:enumeration value="California" />
   <xsd:enumeration value="Arizona" />
   <xsd:enumeration value="Nevada" />
   <xsd:enumeration value="Utah" />
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

When you apply the JAXB's xjc to this type, it produces a Java Enum type:

```
public enum StateType {

    CALIFORNIA,
    ARIZONA,
    NEVADA,
    UTAH;

}
```

My question is how do we define a schema that, when converted to Java class, the class would contain an attribute that can hold a subset of the above enum values? Notice that it should not contain duplicated enum values. A natural choice of such an attribute would be a Set< StateType >, but I don't know how to write a schema that would result in a Set< StateType > attribute in the Java code. The attribute could also be a List< StateType > if we can somehow force the List to not contain duplicated entries. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can define  a scheme with

> `<xsd:unique>`

element.More information can be had from the following link.

[Definitive XML Schema](http://www.datypic.com/books/defxmlschema/chapter17.html)